# How to set Android Button click effect, using different color themes

Tags: java, android

I don't have much experience and only started working on Android applications 2 weeks ago. Sorry in advance if the code or it's approach looks messy.

My current app uses 2 color themes: Dark Theme and Light Theme.
They are created within `styles.xml`.

All my `Buttons` and `TextViews` get `background` color from `attr` folder, where I declared colors. In `colors.xml` I initialized these colors. And in `styles.xml` I set which color belongs to which theme.

Now, back to giving a button click effect - the only way i know how to do that, is to add it as `android:background`.
But i have set for `background` my own color scheme, created in `attr`.
The question is - how to set effect for a button and at the same time keep colors of currently toggled color theme (theme can be changed with `ToggleButton`).

styles.xml

```
<resources>

    <!-- Light theme. -->
    <style name="LightTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <item name="android:textSize">30sp</item>

        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorBtnOperatorsTextLightTheme</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">#306E32</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorPrimary</item>

        <item name="colorBtnOperatorsText">@color/colorBtnOperatorsTextLightTheme</item>
        <item name="colorBtnNumbersText">@color/colorBtnNumbersTextLightTheme</item>
        <item name="colorBtnBackground">@color/colorBtnBackgroundLightTheme</item>
        <item name="colorOutputText">@color/colorOutputLightTheme </item>
        <item name="colorInputText">@color/colorInputLightTheme</item>

        <item name="colorAppBackground">@color/colorAppBackgroundLightTheme</item>
        <item name="android:windowAnimationStyle">@style/WindowAnimationTransition</item>
    </style>

    <!-- Dark theme. -->
    <style name="DarkTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <item name="android:textSize">30sp</item>

        <item name="colorPrimary">#000000</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">#000000</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorPrimary</item>

        <item name="colorBtnOperatorsText">@color/colorBtnOperatorsTextDarkTheme</item>
        <item name="colorBtnNumbersText">@color/colorBtnNumbersTextDarkTheme</item>
        <item name="colorBtnBackground">@color/colorBtnBackgroundDarkTheme</item>
        <item name="colorOutputText">@color/colorOutputDarkTheme</item>
        <item name="colorInputText">@color/colorInputDarkTheme</item>

        <item name="colorAppBackground">@color/colorAppBackgroundDarkTheme</item>
        <item name="android:windowAnimationStyle">@style/WindowAnimationTransition</item>
    </style>

    <style name="WindowAnimationTransition">
        <item name="android:windowEnterAnimation">@android:anim/fade_in</item>
        <item name="android:windowExitAnimation">@android:anim/fade_out</item>
    </style>

</resources>
```

This is how one of the buttons looks like in `activity_main.xml` and next to it - theme color changer - `ToggleButton`

```
<Button
        android:id="@+id/seven"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="7"
        android:textColor="?attr/colorBtnNumbersText"
        android:background="?attr/colorBtnBackground"
        android:onClick="buttonClick"/>

<ToggleButton
        android:id="@+id/colorToggle"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:minWidth="0dp"
        android:minHeight="0dp"
        android:background="@drawable/toggle_selector"
        android:textOff=""
        android:textOn="" />
```

`attrs.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <declare-styleable name="ds" >
        <attr name="colorBtnOperatorsText" format="color" />
        <attr name="colorBtnNumbersText" format="color" />

        <attr name="colorBtnBackground" format="color" />

        <attr name="colorOutputText" format="color" />
        <attr name="colorInputText" format="color" />

        <attr name="colorAppBackground" format="color" />
    </declare-styleable>
</resources>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add Drawable resource file that include selector tag. By the tag you can add click effect. In selector tag you can add first item tag that have a property which is android:state_enabled="false" means selected state and 2nd item tag will be default state of your button. See the example.Use the drawable as background in your example.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_enabled="false" 
        android:drawable="@drawable/selected" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/default" />
</selector>
```

Create two drawables which are selected and default that will include shape tag by the tag you can design your button for selected and default state click effect in your drawable folder. Giving one example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">

    <solid
        android:color="@color/gray"/>
    <corners
        android:radius="@dimen/_10sdp"/>

</shape>
```

Comment: Sorry, could you specify more? I need to have in total 3 drawable files - (One with selector tag and two for selected/default status)? If so, with what parameters I create @drawable /selected and @drawable/default?

Comment: Other two drawables which are selected and default that will include shape tag by the tag you can design your button for selected and default state click effect and use the two tags in first drawable file which include selector tag. Thanks